How to disable google automatically being selected in address bar when pressing G on a new tab?
When I open a new tab and press g, it suggests and selects my google.com bookmark:

However, whenever I open a new tab and press y. It suggests searching for the letter y on google and I have to press the down arrow to select to go to youtube.

The second option is what I prefer where I manually select google from the suggest list rather than have it already selected.
Is there a way to disable google being automatically selected when I enter g?
The about:config preference browser.urlbar.autoFill set to false disables it for all the other websites I have bookmarked, but not google's.
Edit: this is for firefox

@John this is for firefox

@John I'm aware it goes away with more letters. I just don't want it auto selected on G since the other bookmarks don't as well.

Interesting conversation! Does SuperUser not enforce distinct user names? Yes, I see one is user 327522, and the other 1079976 -- but this seems confusing.

@DrMoishePippik nup, its a common name

The answer probably stands in the Settings > Search menu, or about:preferences#search.
In the “Address Bar” section, you may check “Search engines” and uncheck “Bookmarks” and probably “Browsing history”. You may end up with something like that:

